# CentOS SFTP chroot

Tags: linux, centos, sftp, sshd, chroot

I've some issues chrooting an SFTP access for a client.

I can access the directory, but the problem is I can't read / write, I can just access the directory.

Below is what I've done :

```
# cat /etc/passwd | grep comege
comege:x:1001:1001::/home/sftp/comege/home/:/sbin/nologin

# cat /etc/group | grep sftp
sftp-only:x:1001:

# sshd_config
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftp-only
ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/%u
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

SELinux is set on permissive for testing purposes.

When I connect to the server using SFTP I get the following error :

```
Error listing directory '/'. Permission denied
```

Permissions :

```
/home/sftp/comege and parent directories belongs to root:root.

/home/sftp/comege/home belongs to comege:sftp-only
```

I think the issue is comege isn't redirected to /home/sftp/comege/home on connection, so it gets to /home/sftp/comege which belongs to root hence the lack of permissions (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the permissions for the chroot directory, `/home/sftp/comege`, are not set to allow read access by the `comege` user.

Permissions on `/home/sftp/comege` should look like this:

```
# ls -la /home/sftp/comege
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       8 Jul 19 12:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      12 Jul 19 11:59 ..
drwx------ 1 comege sftp-only 76 Jul 19 12:00 home
```

Change the permissions with:

```
# chmod 755 /home/sftp/comege
```

Note this does not take into account SELinux permissions.

By design, an SFTP session in a chrooted environment will start with the user in the chroot "jail" which *must* be owned by root.  It's intended that the user will only write to files in subdirectories of the top-level root directory.  One convention is to create a subdirectory called "incoming" for user uploads instead of the "home" directory shown in the original example.